# Can wget be instructed to follow only links with specific text?

Tags: shell, wget

I have roughly 4000 pages to download, each of which has a single link to the next page. This link always has the same text (and name attribute). I've have read the documentation for wget pretty thoroughly, and there are switches to download only specific extensions, from only certain directories/hosts, and so forth. I can't find anything that suggests it can filter based on link text.

Is there some trick I'm not seeing? The use case seems general enough that I can't imagine I'm the first to ever need it.

Comment: I have to consent that there's no possiblity in `wget` to filter links by link text. Isn't there any pattern in the URLs that you can use to filter via `-I` / `-X` (directories) or `-A` / `-R` (filenames)?

Comment: No pattern that I can see. There's some sort of database internal id number, but it's not sequential... I think it's a pk where some rows have been deleted. But there's always a "Next Page" link, and sometimes "Cont'd." link texts. I've got it in a bash loop, regexing through with perl, but the tests I've run make it seems like I'd see a x10 improvement in speed if wget did it itself. Guess I'll have to live with it as is.

Comment: I could imagine you can improve performance by moving the loop into your perl script, since then you would only invoke the perl interpreter once.